# Get the lambda to reference itself

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to make lambda able to reference to itself, an example:

```
PictureBox pictureBox=...;
Request(() => {
    if (Form1.StaticImage==null)
        Request(thislambda); //What to change to the 'thislambda' variable?
    else
        pictureBox.Image=Form1.StaticImage; //When there's image, then just set it and quit requesting it again
});
```

When I tried to put the lambda in variable, while the lambda referenced to itself, error of course.

I thought about creating class with a method that able to call itself, but I want to stick here with lambda. (While it gives only readibility so far and no advandges)

Comment: declare it as a variable.

Comment: @DanielA.White I said it, when I tried it I got error, something really weird.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to declare the delegate, initialize it to *something* so that you are not accessing an uninitialized variable, and *then* initialize it with your lambda.

```
Action action = null;
action = () => DoSomethingWithAction(action);
```

Probably the most common usage I see is when an event handler needs to remove itself from the event when fired:

```
EventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s, args) =>
{
    DoStuff();
    something.SomeEvent -= handler;
};
something.SomeEvent += handler;
```

Comment: It could stop the confusing if microsoft could make `Action action = () => action();` an exception. Thanks.

Comment: @KugBuBu If they did it could allow someone to evaluate a variable that didn't yet have a value, which is something that they've gone out of their way to make impossible to do.

Comment: I mean to make it an exception. Just for this particular case.

Comment: @KugBuBu And making that exception would allow you to write code that evaluated a variable to its value without that local variable having been assigned a value.  As I said, the C# designers decided that they didn't want to make that possible.

Comment: @KugBuBu I highly recommend you go read "[Minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx)" by Eric Gunnerson, a programmer for Microsoft. It explains very well why stuff like you are suggesting did not get put in.

Comment: It can't be unassigned, the exception I meant is that you make a variable assignment that to make that variable to need a reference to that variable. It's that I want to able to use unassigned variables.

Answer (score 4):

As of C# 7, you can also use local functions:

```
PictureBox pictureBox=...;
void DoRequest() {
    if (Form1.StaticImage == null)
        Request(DoRequest);
    else
        pictureBox.Image = Form1.StaticImage; //When there's image, then just set it and quit requesting it again
}

Request(DoRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting post on the subject from the experts -
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx

Excerpt from the post -
"A quick workaround is to assign the value null to fib and then assign the lambda to fib.  This causes fib to be definitely assigned before it is used.

```
Func<int, int> fib = null;
fib = n => n > 1 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : n;
Console.WriteLine(fib(6)); // displays 8
```

But our C# workaround doesn't really use recursion.  Recursion requires that a function calls itself."

Read the entire post, if you are looking for other fun ways of doing it.

Comment: That most certainly *is* using recursion.  The anonymous method most certainly is invoking itself.  There's a layer of indirection there in that it's going through a delegate, but it's still happening.